# Apache2 server getting too many connection requests

Tags: wordpress, apache, apache2, apache2.4

I am trying to deploy a Nodejs & WordPress website together on an ubuntu server and I am using apache2 for my server config. Everything works fine initially. But after some time my website start showing connection timeout in the browser and when I checked the Ubuntu machine then I found the following:

1. I checked the error log and increased the worker limit but then got this error again.

[image]

2. I also checked the tasks using htop command then I found this and as I am increasing the worker request number in the apache2 config file the tasks increase automatically.

[image]

3. I also checked which IP calling so many requests and then I found this:

[image]

4. Access logs file :
   [image]

I have no idea what is going on here and don't know how to fix it. If anyonw know the solution to this problem then please reply.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of one of the requests? (You can find them in 
 `/var/log/apache2/access.log`, or somewhere else). Could be something like a DDoS attack

Comment: thank you dear Piyush Mittal for this important question - and yes also for some log-insights. These are pretty important!

Comment: @Exampleperson Okay. I checked the access.log and there is so many logs of a single day and I have not opened my website till now. So, It's may be a DDos attack. Can you please suggest me any solution to this.

Comment: @PiyushMittal please show an example request

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Comment: @Exampleperson I added access.log screenshot in the question. Please check and if you know any solution then pls share.

Comment: @PiyushMittal Thanks a lot for that. Now, before you try a solution, you should probably know that these requests seem to be from a person that is trying to DDoS some server, **through** your server, so they are trying to use your server as a proxy.

Comment: @Exampleperson Thank you for the answer. Can you please explain me that how I can get which IP addresses I have to block??

Comment: @PiyushMittal, hmm, you should probably look at the access_log, and block those IPs mentioned for the `CONNECT` requests (they are mentioned at the start of the line). There is one request per line in the access_log.

Comment: @Exampleperson Okay But there are like tons of request in access_log. So, any command to find out those IPs.?

Comment: @PiyushMittal you said you found those IP addresses that are making too many connection attempts (look at your own question). Just block them.

Comment: @Exampleperson But the thing is those IP Addresses change daily.

Comment: @PiyushMittal If that is the case, you should probably use Fail2Ban. Search about it on the internet, you will find how to use it. It will automatically block the IPs making those repeated connection attempts if you configure it properly

Comment: @Exampleperson I configured the fail2ban on my apache2 server but still, I am getting so many requests and I use htop to check my tasks. And It is still so much high. Is there any other solution to this problem? pls share